view function returns 1n instread of 1
I have a view function that i plan to use in order to test with mocha.
 function getNumber() public view returns (uint256){
    return number;
}

The value the view function should return is 1. However, the view function returns 1n.
Thus the mocha test fails.
Could anyone please help me?

It’s basically returning the BigInteger representation of 1 i.e., 1n.
You can just convert it to integer using parseInt() function of JavaScript.
